# FormData vs jQuery#serialize(), What is the difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

Recently I was submitting a form using AJAX.

In researching the best method I saw some AJAX submissions using `jQuery#serialize()` and others using `FormData`. For example.

One submission did this:

```
data: $('form').serialize()
```

while the other did:

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
data: formData
```

So what is the difference between `FormData` and `jQuery#serialize()`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The main difference from a usage standpoint is that you can't serialize files, only file names....the `value` of a file input.

`FormData` object on the other hand also includes files if applicable.

Also `serialize()` will work in older browsers that don't support the FormData API for example IE < 10

reference [FormData docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Answer (score 8):

One more important difference is the treatment of empty input-fields in forms.

```
serialize()
```

only contains input-fields with a value. Unchecked check-boxes or empty input-fields will be missing in the key/value pairs. Therefore the backend of your application will have to do some book-keeping in order to interpret missing keys as empty values.

```
FormData
```

will get you a complete list of all your form fields and their values. Even if they are empty.