# Current request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

i am trying to upload file using below. But i am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1b04024.

When i call form.submit(); instead of form.submit(function(){ using ajax call its working as expected. But i need to return a string value from Spring controller and get in JS function. Below code does working.

Angularjs function:

```
    function fnSubmitUploadForm(formData){
        var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display: none"></iframe>');
        $("body").append(iframe);
        var form = $('#upload');
        form.attr("action", CONTEXT_PATH+"/uploadFile");
        form.attr("method", "post");
        form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
        form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        form.attr("target", "postiframe");
        form.attr("uploadfile", $('#uploadfile').val());
        var input =  $('<input type="hidden" name="filename"/>').val(formData);
        input.appendTo(form);

        form.submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
              url: form.attr('action'),
              type: 'POST',
              data : form.serialize(),
              success: function(){
                alert('form submitted.');
              }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
```

Spring controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/uploadFile", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
    public @ResponseBody String uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){  
        try{
            MultipartFile file =(MultipartFile) request.getFile("uploadfile");
            String[] formData=request.getParameterValues("filename");

        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you are using form serialize in your js submit,it can not serialize form attributes like file type! Have a look at this link:
[FormData vs .serialize(), What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469684/formdata-vs-serialize-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: var formData = new FormData(form); data : formData, When i try this i am getting jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation..

Comment: try: new FormData(form.get(0))

Comment: sorry for trouble you.. var formData1 = new FormData(form.get(0)); same exception i am getting for this too..

Comment: Whether i need to add content type or enc type or mime type in ajax attributes?

Comment: Have a try add  $.ajax{ processData: false, contentType: false} in your ajax request?

Comment: Thank you so much Frio.. I have added and solved it.

Comment: You are welcome~Very happy you can solve it.Please do a little more to accept my answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by below code.

```
form.submit(function(){
    var formData1 = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData1,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(){
            alert('form submitted.');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```